# CSS is not applying in table and How to associate multiple tag inside innnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a `div`. Inside div I wanted one `input` tag one `table` tag which should be scrollable and one span for displaying the message.

I am trying to place css from external file but some reason it is not applying.

The way I am creating is given below.

```
var input = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" title="Type Input">';
var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type Table Value">'
    +'<table id="myTable">'+ '<tr class="header"></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>'+'</table>'; 

div.innerHTML = myTable;
```

div.innerHTML I am adding only myTable.

My CSS :

```
`#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 30%;
  height : 30%;
  overflow-y:auto;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: none;
  margin-top:-12px;
}
```

I wanted to my table should be scrollable. but my table css is not applying on table.
1. Here my css is not getting apply for myTable.
2. How do I add another span just below the table.

Comment: What CSS is not being applied?

Comment: Please make a working example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @torazaburo Sir I updated my question.

Comment: Are you trying to add this css from JS??

Answer (score 0):

Do not give table height, and add your table to another div inside, with CSS  `overflow-y:auto;`.

Comment: Any example/// which I can use

Comment: `var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type Table Value">'
    +'<div id=tdiv ><table id="myTable">'+ '<tr class="header"></tr>' + '<tr><td></td></tr>'+'</table></div>'; `      Along with this add css to `tdiv` `overflow-y:auto;`

Comment: put the code as an edit, makes it much easier to read. Just leave a comment for the OP that you made an edit instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var div = document.getElementById("container");

var input = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()" title="Type Input">';

var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" title="Type Table Value">' +
'<table id="myTable">'+
'<tr class="header"><th>HEADER</th></tr>' +
'<tr><td>CONTENTS</td></tr>'+'</table>';


div.innerHTML = myTable;
```

```css
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#myTable td,th {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

#container {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
  height: 30px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```